# MYSQL - get count of rows from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, count

I hope this is a simple question for someone,
I'm trying to get a count of users that belong to a certain regionID.

I have a users table and a venues table and I want to match the users region and the venues region for a particular regionID.

eg

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users 
LEFT JOIN venues 
ON users.region = venues.region 
WHERE  venues.regionID = '18'
```

My results from various attempts result in millions, to 1 to non responsive page (gulp)

Example table data:

**users**

```
userID = 1  
region = 'Brisbane'
```

**venues**

```
venueID = 1  
region = 'Brisbane'  
regionID = '18'// which equates to Queensland
```

thanks

Comment: You'll either need to describe your goal a bit more clearly, or show us a piece of the original dataset and what your desired query would ultimately return. As of right now, it's not very clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: So, does the query you have shown work?  What does it output?  Why are you using `LEFT JOIN`?  What does `users.region` contain, does it match with `users.region`?

Comment: hmmm I think the question is this statement "count of users that belong to certain regionID", the rest is well unclear

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback, 
My goal is just to get the number of users for a particular regionID, and display this number on the page. 

An example users.region = 'Brisbane' and venues.region = 'Brisbane' and venues.regionID = '18'. 18 will be the number for the state Queensland. So my result should show me a count of  all users that belong to the state queensland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess (without knowing) you want a count of *distinct* users matching your regionId criterion.

You could do this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM users
 WHERE region IN (SELECT region FROM venues WHERE regionID = '18')
```

Or, you could get the number of distinct users in each region like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT users.userID) users,
       region.regionID
  FROM users
  JOIN venues ON users.region = venues.region
 GROUP BY region.regionID
```

I guess you have a `userID` column in your `users` table.

`COUNT(*)` probably won't work in a JOIN, because the result of the join operation probably contains a different number of rows than the `users` table itself.

This is one of those operations where it helps to know lots of SQL even to specify the result you want. Fortunately the `DISTINCT` keyword can help reduce large counts to smaller, and more meaningful counts.

To help with performance, you probably should add a compound index on your `users` table on the `(region, usersID)` columns. This DDL query may do that for you.

```
      ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX region_userID  (region, usersID)
```

Also, on your other table, try these two

```
      ALTER TABLE venues ADD INDEX regionID_region (regionID, region)
      ALTER TABLE venues ADD INDEX region_regionID (region, regionID)
```

Read this:  http://use-the-index-luke/

Comment: thanks for the help. Yes there is a usersID on the users table. 

yeah - count of distinct users matching your regionId criterion. That's right. I will use one of these select statements for each regionID I need to display a count for.


My users table as 120,000 rows and the venues 3,000. Trying the first snippet of code seem to timeout the page.

I'll try the other code snippet out too.
Thanks